# In a box there are balls numbered m to n (n>m) and with returns 2013 are drawn and the numbers on them are registered..

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What is the probability that the largest and smallest registered numbers are $k\ and\ l (m\leq l <k\leq n)?$ Do the assignment in the case that the balls are drawn without returns, $2012\leq k-l$.

first one: ${(k-l)^{2012}}\over{(n-m)^{2012}}$ and second: $2012...(2013-k+l)\over 2012...(2013-n+m)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With replacement the probability that all the $2013$ balls are in the interval from $l$ through to $k$ is $\left(\frac{k-l+1}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013}$ while the the probability that all the balls are in the interval from from $l$ through to $k-1$ is $\left(\frac{k-l}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013}$.

So the probability that all the balls are in the interval from from $l$ through to $k$ and the largest is $k$ is  $\left(\frac{k-l+1}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013} -  \left(\frac{k-l}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013}$, and thus the probability that all the balls are in the interval from from $l+1$ through to $k$ and the largest is $k$ is $\left(\frac{k-l}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013} -  \left(\frac{k-l-1}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013}$.

This means the probability that all the balls are in the interval from from $l$ through to $k$ and the largest is $k$ and the smallest is $l$ is  $\left(\frac{k-l+1}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013} - 2 \left(\frac{k-l}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013} + \left(\frac{k-l-1}{n-m+1}\right)^{2013}$ which can be written as $$\dfrac{({k-l+1})^{2013}-2({k-l})^{2013}+({k-l-1})^{2013}}{({n-m+1})^{2013}}.$$

---

Without replacement there are $\displaystyle {n-m+1 \choose 2013}$ ways of choosing $2013$ balls in the interval from $m$ through to $n$, and $\displaystyle{k-l-1 \choose 2011}$ such that  the largest is $k$ and smallest $l$ with the other $2011$ strictly within that interval.

So the answer should be $$\displaystyle \dfrac{\displaystyle{k-l-1 \choose 2011}}{\displaystyle {n-m+1 \choose 2013}}.$$

Comment: So you think the first one i wrote is correct ?

Comment: See my "with replacement" addition to my answer